# how to filter an array of object, rendering the new value using useState react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I have an array of shoe products stored in useState hook, I would like to:

1. Return a new array of filtered shoes when the checkboxes with the shoe brand is checked.
2. Remove an item from the filtered array when the checkbox is unchecked.
3. Render the filtered product(array) to the DOM

Here is the code

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import { useState } from "react";
import Pagination from '../../../components/Pagination';
import Modal from '../../../components/Modal';


type MenSneakersPageProps = {
  result: any[]
}
 
const MenSneakers: NextPage<MenSneakersPageProps> = ({ result }) => {
  const [fetchedData, setFetchData] = useState(result)
  const [modal, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

  const listOfBrands = function() {
    const arr: string[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (!arr.includes(result[i].brand?.name))
      arr.push(result[i].brand?.name);
    }
    return arr;
  };
  const brandList = listOfBrands()

// tried this but it appends the filtered array to the existing array
  const filterBrandHandler = (event: any) => {

    const { value, checked } = event;
      
    console.log(`${value} is ${checked}`);
     
    if (checked) {
      const filterByBrand = fetchedData.filter(item => item.brand?.name == value)
      setFetchData((current) => [...current, filterByBrand])
    }else {
      const filterByBrand = fetchedData.filter(item => item.brand?.name !== value)
      setFetchData((current) => [...current, filterByBrand])
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='px-2'>

      <Modal onOpen={modal.secondModal} setPopUp={() =>  dispatch({ type:'closeModal2', value: false})}>
        <h2 className='text-2xl border-bottom border-b-4 border-black w-20 font-semibold pb-2'>Brands</h2>
        <hr/> 
        {brandList.sort().filter(item => item !== undefined).map((item, index) => (        
          <ul className='mt-6' key={index}>
            <li className='my-6'>
            <input className="mr-2" type='checkbox' id='brand' value={item} name='brand' onChange={(e) => filterBrandHandler(e.target)}/>
            {item}
            </li>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </Modal>
      <Pagination data={fetchedData} title="" pageLimit={2} dataLimit={30}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MenSneakers
```

the array of shoe product takes this form:

```
[
 {
    id: 18657677,
    shortDescription: 'VL7N panelled logo-print sneakers',
    merchantId: 9564,
    brand: { id: 534369, name: 'Valentino Garavani' },
    gender: 'men',
    images:[Array],
      all: [Array]
    },
    priceInfo: {
      formattedFinalPrice: '$689',
      formattedInitialPrice: '$689',
      finalPrice: 689,
      initialPrice: 689,
      currencyCode: 'USD',
      isOnSale: false,
      discountLabel: null,
      installmentsLabel: null
    },
    merchandiseLabel: 'New Season',
    merchandiseLabelField: 'NewSeason',
    isCustomizable: false,
    availableSizes: null,
    stockTotal: 170,
    url: '/ng/shopping/men/valentino-garavani-vl7n-panelled-logo-print-sneakers-
item-18657677.aspx?storeid=9564',
    promotionLabel: null,
    type: 'Product',
    properties: { rankingTrackingId: 'M5JfpuxHhMlCJl' }
  },
]
```

Comment: Add 1 additional `useState` to `keep the array of selected brands`. Add 1 additional array with `useMemo` that will be the result of filtering the array of items you have based on the array of selected brands. Do not modify the `fetchedData` due to it needs to hold the array of items you got from API.

Comment: @SergeySosunov how do I then render the fetchedData and filtered array in the same component assuming the filter array function is called?

Comment: You dont need to render the `fetchedData`, you will need to render only the `filtered array` which could be the same as `fetchedData` if no filters were applied. So you have 1 useState `fetchedData` to store the original array of items from api, 1 useState array of selected filters and 1 useMemo which will either return the `fetchedData` if no filters, either return `fetchedData.filter(.....)`. And just render it.

Comment: Alright, I understand clearly now. thank you @SergeySosunov